# C++ private variable access in main function

Tags: c++, private-members

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Movie{
    string title;
    string genre;
    int rating;
public:
    Movie(string t, string g);
    void printDetail();
};

Movie :: Movie(string t, string g){
    title = t;
    genre = g;
    rating = rand()%10;      
}

void Movie :: printDetail(){
    cout <<" Title  : " <<title<<endl;
    cout <<"    Genre  : " <<genre<<endl;
    cout <<"    Rating : " <<rating<<endl;
}
```

And in the `main` I have the following:

```
int main()
{
   Movie M[5]={
        Movie("The Avengers","Action"),
        Movie("Infinity War","Action"),
        Movie("Gupigain Baghabain","Comedy"),
        Movie("Anonymous 616","Horror"),
        Movie("Sara's Notebook","Thriller")
        };

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            cout <<" "<<i+1<<".";
            M[i].printDetail();
            cout<<endl;
        }

        M[0].rating; // Here i need to access to rating...!!

       // Here I need to compare which movies rating is highest..!! 
       // So I need to access rating variable...!! 
       // But how can I do this...!! 
       // There has a condition... That is I can't declare any other member function..!!!
}
```

Here I have to show which one's rating is highest and which one's rating is lowest..!!

Comment: Make it public.

Comment: So you have a private member and you want to access it without declaring any member functions? You can't unless you use very nasty pointer hacks which involve undefined behavior. The whole point of private members is to prevent non-member functions from accessing implementation details and make sure they use the public interface instead.

Comment: Don't yell. It doesn't make your question any cleaner.

Comment: C++ encapsulation was born just to disable that.

Comment: You can make rating public or protected. Alternatively, You can declare another class , have Movie declare that this class is a friend, declare a public method in that class that takes a movie and returns the rating. Ugly stuff.

Comment: These members are called literally _private_. Why would any function be able to access them? It's like your home address is private for you, and nobody can access it that easily.

Comment: Movie class will have three private member variable: title, genre and rating.
Create a parameterized constructor for the Movie class to initialized: title, genre and rating.
Movie class will have one member function: void printDetail(). printDetail() functions will print the detail of the movie.
In main function create an array of Movie object. The size of the array will be inputted by the user. 
Use rand() to generate the value of rating of every movie. Value of rating must be in a range of 0 and 10.
Now, find the movie with highest and lowest rating from the array. **This are conditon**

Comment: Add a member function that can answer the question (by accessing the private member variable). Or make the variable `public`. The whole *point* of `private` members is that they are *private* and cannot be accessed outside the class.

Comment: Reading your assignment I do not see the "Do not add any member functions." Did you forget to add that or is it really not in the assigment?

Comment: Thanks @tkausl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make getter and setter functions to access the private members indirectly
There is another hack which isn't standard : get the offest of the private member to the class head then get the address of the class and add the offest to it thus you have the address of the private member and can access it directly
This isn't supported by the standard c++ and you need to do the calculations yourself , in your case it isn't difficult
This method can be used when you want to get a structure or class from a dll to obtain a value of particular member and you don't have the definition of the structure but you can obtain the rva offest from the dll using various methods like disassembling some bytes of the dll

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the class:

```
bool isHighest(Movie otherMovie){
return rating > otherMovie.rating;
}
```

If you want, you can make it an operator:

```
bool operator >(Movie otherMovie){
return rating > otherMovie.rating;
}
```

Comment: oh.. Thanks. @רועי אבידן